# Is it possible to log at DEBUG level to file and INFO level to console in logback?

Tags: java, logback

I tried the following logback-test.xml

```
<configuration>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%d{ISO8601} | %-5level | %thread | %logger{1} | %m%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </root>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <file>logs/integration.log</file>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%d{ISO8601} | %-5level | %thread | %logger{1} | %m%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

but console is still at DEBUG level. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should consider using LevelFilter. So you set root level as debug and then apply level filter for your appenders. Here is an example configuration:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <file>myFile.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>myFile.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>10 MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c{0} - %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Read more in this article: https://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2014/09/27/logging-different-log-levels-to-different-appenders-with-logback/

Comment: updated filters to correspond the goal of the answer: file at debug level and console at info level

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Alex M981. I will try it out. But, I wish I could achieve the same with less verbose xml. That seems like a lot of xml to do something simple.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I am always trying to use loggers in this way and it always seems counter to the way they were designed to be used.  Agreeing with other users about XML I am referring to other SO posts for how to do this in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014740/configure-logback-under-spring-using-java-and-not-xml/57015575